# Página não retorna o ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-bean

já vi vários posts parecidos, mas não ajudou muito. Meu problema é bem simples. Eu tenho uma página com formulário que irá gravar dados e exibir em uma tabela utilizando o ManagedBean. Porém quando clico para gravar, o console mostra o seguinte erro:

**Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier [carroBean] resolved to null**

Código Bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class CarroBean {

    private Carro carro;
    private List<Carro> listaCarros = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void adicionar() {
        listaCarros.add(carro);
        carro = new Carro();
    }
    public Carro getCarro() {
        return carro;
    }
    public void setCarro(Carro carro) {
        this.carro = carro;
    }
    public List<Carro> getListaCarros() {
        return listaCarros;
    }
    public void setListaCarros(List<Carro> listaCarros) {
        this.listaCarros = listaCarros;
    }
}
```

Código XHTML

```
<h:form>
        <p:fieldset legend="Objetos" style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="2">
                
                <p:outputLabel value="Modelo"/>
                <p:inputText value="#{carroBean.carro.modelo}"/>
                
                <p:outputLabel value="Fabricante"/>
                <p:inputText value="#{carroBean.carro.fabricante}"/>
                
                <p:outputLabel value="Cor"/>
                <p:inputText value="#{carroBean.carro.cor}"/>
                
                <p:outputLabel value="Ano"/>
                <p:inputText value="#{carroBean.carro.ano}"/>
                
                <p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{carroBean.adicionar}" update="@form"/>
                
                <p:dataTable value="#{carroBean.listaCarros}" var="carros">
                    <p:column headerText="Modelo">
                        <h:outputText value="#{carros.modelo}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Fabricante">
                        <h:outputText value="#{carros.fabricante}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Cor">
                        <h:outputText value="#{carros.cor}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Ano">
                        <h:outputText value="#{carros.ano}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:fieldset>
    </h:form>
```

Já tentei mudar o botão para actionListener, adicionar o ViewScoped, o RequestScoped, nada. Outra coisa, não sei se é bug do Eclipse, mas na página xhtml quando você tenta autocompletar o Bean, ele só complete os atributos, mas o método não, eu tenho que escrever manualmente. Como complemento, minha configuração, estou utilizando o JSF 2.2.9 e não estou utilizando o Maven, apenas o Dynamic Project 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

meu problema era mais de atenção mesmo. Depois de rever o código, consegui ver que esqueci de instanciar um novo objeto no meu código Bean.

```
private Carro carro = new Carro();

public void adicionar() {
        listaCarros.add(carro);
        carro = new Carro();
    }
```

Sendo assim, agora está finalizado e resolvido.